# How can I conditionally suppress logging in Express (or Connect)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

When using the logger middleware which is part of Connect (as well as Express), I would like to be able to disable logging on certain requests, say by setting a flag on the response or something.

I managed to do it by saying:

```
res.doNotLog = true;
```

and then, deep in logger.js (part of the Connect module), I put

```
if(res.doNotLog) return;
```

in the right place.  But of course I don't want to be modifying code in the module itself.  Is there any way I can cause the same to happen without having to hack the module?

**Edit:**

This worked:

```
var app = _express.createServer();

// set 'hello' routing...note that this is before middleware 
// so it won't be logged
app.get('/sayhello', function(req, res) {res.send("hey");});

// configure middleware: logging, static file serving
app.configure(function() {
    app.use(_express.logger());
    app.use(_express.static(__dirname + '/www'));
  });

// set 'goodbye' routing...note that this is after middleware 
// so it will be logged
app.get('/saygoodbye', function(req, res) {res.send("later...");});
```

Comment: This did not work for me and only seemed to log initial requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious thing would be to put the handlers for those requests before the logger. This is easy in pure Connect, not sure how to do it in Express because a lot of the router code is shared between routes. If there were only a few such requests, you could handle them Connect-style earlier in the stack than `app.router`.

Comment: If you have the time, it would be nice to show us just how you did it. That would make this question the sort of thing we could point other people to when they have a similar problem. Also, although I have a general idea of how I'd do it, your implementation might actually be better.

Comment: sure thing, done.  I guess the trick is separating the app.configure() from _express.createServer()...but they were already separate in mine so it was just a matter of moving the call to app.get().  :)

Comment: @rob The answer should be in the answer, though, not in the question.